# AWK, SED or GREP for extracting data from HTML file

Tags: sed, awk, grep, regular-expression, html

Can anyone tell me which is best to use to extract the following data from a html file which was received with curl .

```
<script>document.getElementById("test-summary").innerHTML = "<strong>Test Pages:</strong> 1 right, 0 wrong, 0 ignored, 0 exceptions&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

I will need only the part where `1 right, 0 wrong, 0 ignored, 0 exceptions` . based on the following tag :  `document.getElementById("test-summary")` . 
These are some test results and I will need to make some logic based on these .

If anyone can give a suggestion on how to do this I would be very grateful .

Many thanks,

Istvan Caluser

Comment: `awk -F '<|>|&' '/test-summary/{print $7}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not super elegant, but here you go:

```
sed -ne 's/.*"test-summary".* \([0-9][0-9]* right [^&].*exceptions\)&nbsp.*/\1/p'
```

For example:

```
$ echo '<script>document.getElementById("test-summary").innerHTML = "<strong>Test Pages:</strong> 1 right, 0 wrong, 0 ignored, 0 exceptions&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' | sed -ne 's/.*"test-summary".* \([0-9][0-9]* right,[^&].*exceptions\)&nbsp.*/\1/p'
1 right, 0 wrong, 0 ignored, 0 exceptions
```

Comment: It doesn't return anything , and I'm not familiar with sed's syntax .

Comment: @CaluserIstvan What are you running?  You have to pipe your HTML to that program, or add a command-line parameter that is the name of the file with the HTML output.

Comment: I was trying to run in directly on a file piping it works , thank you very much ! :)

Answer (score 0):

With `grep` and `awk`:

```
grep 'document.getElementById("test-summary")' file.html | awk -F'</strong>|&' '{print $2}'
```